# Microsoft Macro Assembler tab does not show up in my VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Although I have enabled masm checked box in my project properties under build dependencies tab but the Microsoft Macro assemble tab does not show up in my project properties. Is that a bug in my vs2013 or something else?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the answers to the following question for some things to try: [How to enable Assembly Language support in Visual Studio 2013](/questions/20078021/how-to-enable-assembly-language-support-in-visual-studio-2013/31922830)

I had the same problem, but I was able to get `Microsoft Macro Assembler` to appear in the project configuration panel by following one of the suggestions listed at the above page. Specifically, I right-clicked an .asm file in the project and set the `Item Type` to `Microsoft Macro Assembler`. When I re-opened the project configuration, `Microsoft Macro Assembler` magically appeared in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Not a bug neither an issue in the visual Studio.All that you are making mistake is not making tick on the empty project while making a new win32 project.That popup menu comes when you make a new project and you have to tick the empty project checkbox then it will be available as you asked.